# How to make reusable widget in flutter card swiper?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-slider, flutter-audio-query

I'm attempting to use the Flutter `Swiper` with different parameters on the same page, however I'm unsure how to structure the code.

I want this same code in Multiple Pages I was tried several way but it doesn't work.
So I want make this Widget as Reusable

```
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';
import 'package:card_swiper/card_swiper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Animals extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimalsState createState() => _AnimalsState();
}

class _AnimalsState extends State<Animals> {
  List images = [
    'assets/images/img/getStart.jpg',
    'assets/images/a/a.jpg',
    'assets/images/a/b.jpg',
    'assets/images/a/c.jpg',
    'assets/images/a/d.jpg',
    'assets/images/a/e.jpg',
    'assets/images/a/f.jpg'
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Animals'),
      ),
      body: Swiper(
        itemCount: images.length,
        loop: false,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(27.0),
            child: Image.asset(
              images[index],
            ),
          );
        },
        indicatorLayout: PageIndicatorLayout.COLOR,
        onIndexChanged: (index) {
          playaudio(index);
        },
        autoplayDelay: 10000,
        autoplay: true,
        pagination: SwiperPagination(),
        control: SwiperControl(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void playaudio(index) async {
  AssetsAudioPlayer.newPlayer().open(
    Audio('assets/audio/a/a$index.mp3'),
    autoStart: true,
    loopMode: LoopMode.none,
    showNotification: true,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new dart class and create a custom widget that you can use anywhere in your application like below (dont forget to import  'package:flutter/material.dart';"  in cutom swiper class)

```
Widget customSwiper({List image }){
return Swiper(
    itemCount: images.length,
    loop: false,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(27.0),
        child: Image.asset(
          images[index],
        ),
      );
    },
    indicatorLayout: PageIndicatorLayout.COLOR,
    onIndexChanged: (index) {
      playaudio(index);
    },
    autoplayDelay: 10000,
    autoplay: true,
    pagination: SwiperPagination(),
    control: SwiperControl(),
  ),
);
}
```

Now use customSwiper as you use other Flutter Material widget anywhere in the application and you can add parameter according to your need.

Comment: playaudio() in  index bro

Comment: can you elaborate your query